# Strict conflict resolution in sbt finds strange conflicts

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a big sbt project, and we use strict conflict resolution, so we have to put in a lot of overrides.

Among the more puzzling conflicts we get are these:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.1.1 (needed by [com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk;1.8.9.1]) conflicts with com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.2.2 (needed by [])`

Version 2.2.2 is needed by nothing?

Another one is this one:

`commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 (needed by
[org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.3.1,
com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk;1.8.9.1]) conflicts with
commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 (needed by
[com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk;1.8.9.1])`

The same package (aws-java-sdk 1.8.9.1) needs two different versions of commons-logging.

I can easily get around these by putting in more overrides, but it shakes my trust in the conflict resolver. Are these messages harmful? How do I get rid of them without putting in overrides?

Answer (score 1):

There's a *SettingKey* for that: `dependencyOverrides`, which takes a `Set[ModuleID]`:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.2.2",
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.3"
)
```

Any conflict of dependencies found in the set, will be resolved by these overrides.
for more information, consult [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Forcing+a+revision+without+introducing+a+dependency).

Comment: I know about setting overrides. What I'm wondering about is, what do those error messages mean? What is `needed by []`? How can one package depend on two different versions of the same package at the same time?

Comment: it may depend on 2 third party dependencies, which in turn depend on different versions of the same artifact. there's a great plugin I use a lot to inspect dependencies: [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph), you can use it to see where the dependencies are coming from.